# From ByteBuffer to double array

Tags: java, nio, bytebuffer, nio2

I have a [`ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) containing three double values, e.g. `{1.0, 2.0, 3.0}`. What I have now is

```
double[] a = new double[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    a[i] = byteBuffer.getDouble();
}
```

which works fine, but I would prefer a one-step solution via

```
double[] a = byteBuffer.asDoubleBuffer().array();
```

but this results in a exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException at java.nio.DoubleBuffer.array(...)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/DoubleBuffer.html#array--), `array` is an optional operation:

> ```
> public final double[] array()
> ```
>
> Returns the double array that backs this buffer (*optional operation*).

You can tell if calling `array` is OK by calling `hasArray()`.

You can make an array as follows:

```
DoubleBuffer dbuf = byteBuffer.asDoubleBuffer(); // Make DoubleBuffer
double[] a = new double[dbuf.remaining()]; // Make an array of the correct size
dbuf.get(a);                               // Copy the content into the array
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in my opinion, since it not only explained what was I wrong, but actually gave a working solution.

Answer (score 6):

You're misusing `DoubleBuffer`. `DoubleBuffer.array()` returns the array that's backing the `DoubleBuffer` *if and only if* it is the kind of `DoubleBuffer` that is backed by an array. This one isn't. It's backed by a `ByteBuffer`. In fact, this `DoubleBuffer` is just a view of the original `ByteBuffer`.

You can find out whether any particular `ByteBuffer` is backed by an array by invoking the `hasArray()` method.

See Peter Lawrey's answer for the code to get the contents of a `DoubleBuffer` into an array of `double`. (He beat me to it. :-) )

Answer (score 4):

The `DoubleBuffer` has two modes: it can either work by **allocation** or as a **view**. This is decided exclusively at the time of the creation of the `DoubleBuffer`.

The `array()` method is **optional** and will throw a `UnsupportedOperationException` if you're using it from the view.

In your case, coming from a `ByteBuffer` to a `DoubleBuffer` using the method `ByteBuffer::asDoubleBuffer`, you get a view, as mentioned in the Javadoc. And since it's a view, you get the exception.

Answer (score 2):

You can copy to a `double[]` with this.

```
double[] doubles = new double[byteBuffer.remaining() / Double.BYTES];
byteBuffer.asDoubleBuffer().get(doubles);
```

Comment: That's the part I was missing. Thanks!